# Browser requests the same files declared in a setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, get, background-image

I use JavaScript to change the `background-image` of a `div` dynamically every 4 seconds. my code looks like this:

```js
const images = [
    'img/landing-min.jpg',
    'img/gallery-1.jpg',
    'img/side-img.jpg',
];

window.onload = () => {
    const landing = document.getElementById('landing');
    landing.dataset.i = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
        landing.style.backgroundImage = `url(${images[landing.dataset.i]})`;
        landing.dataset.i = (landing.dataset.i+1) % images.length;
    }, 4000)
}
```

The problem is that the browser makes a request to get the file each time the interval changes the background image, which makes a lot of duplicate requests. I want all files to be requested only once.

Comment: Why you don't set the images as css background to a class and just add/ remove it `landing.classList.add('desired-class-name')` in the setInterval loop? The css file is just once loaded by browser, so you are sure to load it just once all images.

Comment: @lortschi Thanks that worked! But I need to have a control on the number of images and their URLs in one place because they are frequently modified. In that way I will have to create a class for each image and then go to the script to add the class name, which would be complicated to another developer using my code.